# How to Select records from table inside another table and making joing

Tags: sql

I'd really appreciate some help with an SQL query across tables.
I have:

- Table A1 inside Table A
- B1 inside Table B.
  I want to select columns from table A1 that have a corresponding tag in table

**A1 table**

> ```
> Id       type message
> 1        2    'hello'
> 102      0    'bye'
> 302      2    'hey'
> ```

**B1 Table**

```
Id      data     refId   
1       70       102
2       6        2
3       8        302
```

**Expected result:**

> ```
> Id       type data
> 1        2    
> 102      0    70
> 302      2    8
> ```

What i did:

```
SELECT Id, type, B.B1.data 
FROM A.A1 a
INNER JOIN B.B1 b ON a.id = b.refid
;
```

Comment: And how result of your attempt differs from expected?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Based on this [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fw6Xw2PWvArWAyRb4sYzY5/0) `Id` column is ambiguous between tables `A1` and `B1`, hence you should prefix it with either `a.` or `b.` in `SELECT` list.

Comment: But, more import then telling you how to fix this, is you telling us which error you got. Future readers can then see if this question/answer can interest them because it's about a subject they can learn from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `left join` instead of `inner join`, to returns all rows from the left table A1, even if there are no matches in the right table B1.

```
SELECT a.Id, a.type, b.data 
FROM A.A1 a
LEFT JOIN B.B1 b ON a.id = b.refid
```

NB : Use aliases for better readability

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/C7lduRDh)

Comment: and when you are using PostgreSQL, you can see demo here: https://dbfiddle.uk/nLl--3rX   (I was just ready when this was posted...)